# moving an object with 2d transformations

Tags: graphics, homogenous-transformation

given the square on the left , I need to make the square on the right with the transformations.

this is my attempt
[image]
however when I checked it on one of the points (for example point D(-1,1)) , I didn't get the correct result (D(4,4,)).

I don't understand where is my mistake.

Is the rotation correct (-90)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation you want is -45°. Remember that you're rotating about the origin `A(0,0)`, not about the center of your square.

Your translation is also a bit off, but I'm sure you'll figure it out once you've got the rotation fixed.